# Can not consume messages from Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

I have defined a Kafka cluster of two nodes with a replication factor of 2. When I try to consume messages using the console consumer it doesn't do anything, it just waits.

**Producer**
`./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic adi`

**Consumer**
`./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic adi --from-beginning`

**Cluster Description**
 Running `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic adi` renders:

```
Topic:adi       PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2   Configs:segment.bytes=1073741824        Topic: adi      Partition: 0    Leader: 3     Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 3,2
```

**P.S**
All I did was follow the [Kafka Quickstart Tutorial](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

Comment: Have you wrote `--topic adi--from-beginning` or `--topic adi --from-beginning`?

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: I assume you have produced some messages with `kafka-console-producer.sh`. When you send several messages (i.e: write some characters/words and press ENTER on the interactive console-producer.sh script) you fail to receive the same messages in the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` window?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what happens.I do not receive nothing in the consumer terminal.It just waits.

Comment: Increase log level to debug - does the client have problems finding the brokers? You'd get a lot of exceptions from `NetworkClient`. One of things I do then is actually replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` and explicitly setting up server config to listen & advertise itself (`advertised.listeners` property) on `127.0.0.1:9002` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Add the other broker address as well in the kafka-console-consumer and check.

You are probably not consuming from the leader replica, try

> ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,
>   other-broker:other-port  --topic adi --from-beginning

Make sure you are running prod/consumer from the same server, it's better to use the server ip instead of the localhost.

Comment: Kafka does discovery of servers, it's enough to provide only one server. Even the property name implies that - it's just the bootstrap for finding the other cluster members.